# Replacing often used piece of code with Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, macros, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator (2.7.0) and I'd like to write certain piece of code in a shorter way, without creating an additional function of it.

Imagine a class:

```
class Car {
public:
    Car(const int velocity=0);
    int getVelocity() const;
    void setVelocity(const int velocity);
private:
    int m_velocity;
};
```

Other methods of our car (or methods of other classes) often need to call this short piece of code:

```
int v = getVelocity();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    // Some behavior
    setVelocity(v + i);
}
```

The *"Some behavior"* part is obviously different every time.

Is there a way to make it so I could just write something like:

```
velocity {
    // Some behavior
}
```

Or something similar, pretty and short?

Comment: If you have C++11 functionality available to you, you can make a function do the iteration for you and you would just pass in a lambda to it.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 I'm afraid I'll have to stick with C++98 for now.

Comment: If there is any solution with lambda functions, the classic C function pointers can be used too. However you have to define a function for each behavior; you can't write arbitrary code then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well not exactly looks like your post, but macros can do the job:

```
#define velocity(SOME_BEHAVIOR)            \
    int v = getVelocity();                 \
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v; i++) { \
        SOME_BEHAVIOR                      \
        setVelocity(v + i);                \
    }
```

Use it like:

```
velocity (
    // Some behaviour
)
```

Take the usual cautions when working with macros, specially be careful about braces when calling the macro.